# Node.js namespacing

Tags: node.js

Struggling a little to make best use of Node's module/require()/exports set up to do proper OO programming.  Is it good practice to create global namespace and not use exports (as in client side js app development)? So, in module (Namespace.Constructor.js):

```
Namespace = Namespace || {};
Namespace.Constructor = function () {
    //initialise
}
Namespace.Constructor.prototype.publicMethod = function () {
    // blah blah
}
```

... and in calling file just use...

```
requires('Namespace.Constructor');
var object = new Namespace.Constructor();
object.publicMethod();
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `exports` or `module.exports`. Your module is already namespaced. Just follow [these docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In node.js, the module location is the namespace, so there's no need to namespace in the code as you've described. I think there are some issues with this, but they are manageable. Node will only expose the code and data that you attach to the module.exports object.

In your example, use the following:

```
var Constructor = function() {
  // initialize
}
Constructor.prototype.publicMethod = function() {}
module.exports = Constructor;
```

And then, in your calling code:

```
var Constructor = require('./path/to/constructor.js');
var object = new Constructor();
object.publicMethod();
```

Comment: But if we don't use var, a global is created and is available to caller.  Why then do we need to use exports at all?

Comment: To avoid a collision of names in the global space. Of course you could create your own namespace system, but require() works reasonably well and is the clear standard in node.js development.

Comment: hacklikecrack: Missing a var in a module does not create a global that is available from the caller. Node automatically wraps your module code in a function to prevent that.