# Namespaces in node.js with require

Tags: node.js, require, vows

I am playing around and learning about vows with a personal project. This is a small client side library, with testing done in vows. Therefore, I must build and test a file that is written like this:

```
(function(exports) { 
    var module = export.module = { "version":"0.0.1" }; 
    //more stuff
})(this);
```

In my testing (based off of [science.js](https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js/), d3, etc.) requires that module like so:

```
require("../module");
```

I continued to get a "module not defined error" when trying to run the tests, so I went to a repl and ran:

```
require("../module")
```

and it returned:

```
{ module: { version: "0.0.1" } }
```

I realize I could do something like:

```
var module = require("../module").module;
```

but feel like I am creating a problem by doing it that way, especially since the libraries that I based this project on are doing it in the format I described.

I would like for my project to behave similar to those which I based it off of, where:

```
require("../module");
```

creates a variable in this namespace:

```
module.version; //is valid.
```

I have seen this in a variety of libraries, and I am following the format and thought process to the T but believe I might be missing something about require behavior I don't know about.

Comment: Related: [Node.js namespacing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9101028/320399)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no problem creating it this way. Modules define what they return in the `module.exports` object. By the way, you don't actually need self executing functions (SEF), there is no global leakage like in browsers :-)

### Examples

module1.js:

```
module.exports = {
    module: { 'version': '0.1.1' }
};
```

main.js:

```
var module1 = require( './module1.js' );
// module1 has what is exported in module1.js
```

---

Once you've understood how this works, you can easily export the version number right away if you want to:

module1.js:

```
module.exports = '0.1.1';
```

main.js:

```
var module1 = require( './module1.js' );
console.log( module1 === '0.1.1' ); // true
```

---

Or if you want some logic, you can easily extend your `module1.js` file like this:

```
module.exports = ( function() {
    // some code
    return version;
} () ); // note the self executing part :-)
// since it's self executed, the exported part
// is what's returned in the SEF
```

---

Or, as many modules do, if you want to export some utility functions (and keep others "private"), you could do it like this:

```
module.exports = {
    func1: function() {
        return someFunc();
    },

    func2: function() {},

    prop: '1.0.0'
};

// This function is local to this file, it's not exported
function someFunc() {
}
```

So, in main.js:

```
var module1 = require( './module1.js' );
module1.func1(); // works
module1.func2(); // works
module1.prop; // "1.0.0"
module1.someFunc(); // Reference error, the function doesn't exist
```

### Your special case

About your special case, I wouldn't recommend doing it like they're doing.

If you look here: https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js/blob/master/science.v1.js

You see that they're not using the `var` keyword. So, they're creating a **global variable**.

This is why they can access it once they `require` the module defining the global variable.

And by the way, the `exports` argument is useless in their case. It's even misleading, since it actually is the `global` object (equivalent of `window` in browsers), not the `module.exports` object (`this` in functions is the global object, it'd be `undefined` if strict mode were enabled).

### Conclusion

Don't do it like they're doing, it's a bad idea. Global variables are a bad idea, it's better to use node's philosophy, and to store the required module in a variable that you reuse.

If you want to have an object that you can use in client side and test in node.js, here is a way:

yourModule.js:

```
// Use either node's export or the global object in browsers
var global = module ? module.exports : window.yourModule;

( function( exports ) {
    var yourModule = {};
    // do some stuff
    exports = yourModule;
} ( global ) );
```

Which you can shorten to this in order to avoid creating the `global` variable:

```
( function( exports ) {
    var yourModule = {};
    // do some stuff
    exports = yourModule;
} ( module ? module.exports : window.yourModule ) );
```

This way, you can use it like this on the client-side:

```
yourModule.someMethod(); // global object, "namespace"
```

And on the server side:

```
var yourModule = require( '../yourModule.js' );
yourModule.someMethod(); // local variable :-)
```

Just FYI, `..` means "parent directory". This is the relative path of where to get the module. If the file were in the same directory, you'd use `.`.

Comment: Thanks Florian, this cleared a lot of issues up on how Node handles require and the module's namespace.

Comment: Though, this is a client side library that I am creating, and have unit tests for it with vows via node. That being said, I think the SEF is a necessity, but, when I include the SEF it makes require("../module) return {module:{"stuff":"value" }} so, I'm wrapping a SEF with node's own manager that handles namespace issues, so my module seems to become relatively useless, I based this testing methodology off of: science.js, d3.js and dc.js. Rather than setting a variable to the exports: var d3 = require("d3"); in all the tests it does: require("d3"); and calls d3 directly.

Comment: I don't know why this behavior occurs, though it seems to work really well for building, testing and maintaining client side libraries with node. I don't know what is going on, and if you could take a look at it I would be very appreciative. If not, thanks a lot you definitely cleared up some stuff I had with working and creating server side modules.

Comment: If you like this answer, upvote it! :) I don't get what you mean in your comment though. If you feel that you need to expand on your problem, don't hesitate to edit your question.

Comment: @MilesMcCrocklin I edited my answer to add an explanation about your special case at the end :)