# How to use jquery into node interactive mode ( REPL like)?

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way to import node modules e.g. jQuery into node interactive mode?

e.g.

```
$ node
> import jquery
> $.map(myArray).function(n){console.log(n)}
```

Comment: Add jQuery to your package.json (or install it globally), launch the REPL, then: `$ = require('jquery');`

Comment: @Florent thanks. that's the answer. I have it installed globally, just didn't knew how to import/require it into repl context. If you put that an answer I can accept it.

Comment: You really shouldn't install modules globally unless you're depending on an executable in that module.  It ends up getting a bit messy, plus upgrading node has a number of times changed where it looks for global modules, so that's not a terribly dependable solution.

Comment: For functions like `map`, you might want to consier using `underscore` instead of jQuery...

Comment: This is Node, which is based on V8, which is ES5 compliant. Just use `Array.prototype.map`, which here is just `myArray.map(function (n) {console.log(n);})`. Do not use underscore, or lodash, and certainly not jQuery for this in Node.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js namespacing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101028/node-js-namespacing)